# Laravel Eloquent ORM: Accessing a specific cell of table

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to access a specific cell of a table. I have to run the following query in Laravel Eloquent ORM:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=$id;
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$user=new users;//users is model
$user=users::where('email',$email)
   ->where('password',$pass)
   ->get();
$mail=$user->email;
```

And I encounter this error:

> ErrorException in HomeController.php line 52: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$email

Any help?

Comment: `->get()` returns a collection, `->first()` returns a model. Either replace `get()` with `first()`, or do `$user->first()->email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd put this up as answer for anyone else that comes looking -

`->get()` returns a collection, `->first()` returns a model.

Either replace `->get()` with `->first()`, or do `$user->first()->email`.